# Finding out product structure in manifolds

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, self-learning

I came across the concept of fiber bundles as manifolds having locally the structure of a product. My question is the following. Suppose you are given a manifold $M$ but does not know if it has a "product structure". Are there ways, given a manifold M, to somehow "reverse"engineer if the manifold has a product structure, that is, if and when it is possible for $M$ to be homeomorphic to the total space $E$ of a bundle, $\pi : E \rightarrow N$ (of course $N$ must be found, along the projection $\pi$).

Does the question make some sense?

**Random thoughts:** in a fiber bundle $\pi : E \rightarrow N$ a local trivialization provides a homeomorphism $\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U \times R^k$. From here we have probably local coordinates of the form $(x_1,\dots,x_n,v_1,\ldots,v_k)$, the first $n$ coordinates coming from a local chart in $M$ and the last $k$ from the fiber.
Instead, given a manifold $M$ a local chart would provide some coordinates $(y_1,\ldots,y_r)$. Can we somehow identify the $y_1,\ldots,y_t$ with $t<r$ as coordinates of a smaller manifold?

Comment: What is "manyfold?"

Comment: just a sign of my ignorance :)... changed

Comment: OK. In general, such questions are very difficult and I doubt that you have sufficient background to read the relevant papers. Here is one: Farrell, F. T. The obstruction to fibering a manifold over a circle. Indiana Univ. Math. J.21(1971/72/1972), 315–346.

Comment: Yes indeed I do not have the background. Still it is interesting for me just a very high level answer. Do you want to expand slightly your comment as an answer so I accept it?

Comment: Yes, once the strike is over....